# Android Continuous speech recognition returns ERROR_NO_MATCH too quickly

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I've tried to implement continuous SpeechRecognition mechanism.
When I start speech recognition I get following messages in logcat:

```
06-05 12:22:32.892 11753-11753/com.aaa.bbb D/SpeechManager: startSpeechRecognition: 
06-05 12:22:33.022 11753-11753/com.aaa.bbb D/SpeechManager: onError: Error 7
06-05 12:22:33.352 11753-11753/com.aaa.bbb D/SpeechManager: onReadyForSpeech: 
06-05 12:22:33.792 11753-11753/com.aaa.bbb D/SpeechManager: onBeginningOfSpeech: Beginning
06-05 12:22:34.492 11753-11753/com.aaa.bbb D/SpeechManager: onEndOfSpeech: Ending
06-05 12:22:34.612 11753-11753/com.aaa.bbb D/SpeechManager: onError: Error 7
```

and this error 7 which means ERROR_NO_MATCH. As you see it is called almost immediately. Isn't it inproper behavior?

Here are full logs between startSpeechRecognition and first error 7:

```
06-05 12:22:32.892 11753-11753/com.aaa.bbb D/SpeechManager: startSpeechRecognition: 
06-05 12:22:32.932 4600-4600/? I/GRecognitionServiceImpl: #startListening [en-US]

                                                      --------- beginning of system
06-05 12:22:32.932 3510-7335/? V/AlarmManager:  remove PendingIntent] PendingIntent{6307291: PendingIntentRecord{2af25f6 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox startService}}
06-05 12:22:32.932 4600-4600/? W/LocationOracle: Best location was null
06-05 12:22:32.932 3510-4511/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 3 index 90
06-05 12:22:32.942 3510-7335/? D/SensorService: SensorEventConnection::SocketBufferSize, SystemSocketBufferSize - 102400, 2097152
06-05 12:22:32.942 3510-7360/? D/Sensors: requested delay = 66667000, modified delay = 0
06-05 12:22:32.942 3510-7360/? I/Sensors: Proximity old sensor_state 16384, new sensor_state : 16512 en : 1
06-05 12:22:32.952 4600-4600/? D/SensorManager: registerListener :: 5, TMD4903 Proximity Sensor, 66667, 0,  
06-05 12:22:32.952 4600-11932/? D/SensorManager: Proximity, val = 8.0  [far]
06-05 12:22:32.952 3510-5478/? I/Sensors: Acc old sensor_state 16512, new sensor_state : 16513 en : 1
06-05 12:22:32.952 3510-4705/? I/Sensors: Mag old sensor_state 16513, new sensor_state : 16529 en : 1
06-05 12:22:32.952 3510-4037/? I/AppOps: sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10068 , packageName=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox , type=startOp
06-05 12:22:32.962 3510-4511/? D/SensorService: GravitySensor2 setDelay  ns = 66667000  mindelay = 66667000
06-05 12:22:32.962 3510-4511/? I/Sensors: RotationVectorSensor old sensor_state 16529, new sensor_state : 147601 en : 1
06-05 12:22:32.972 3510-3617/? V/BroadcastQueue: [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{f9fab82 u0 com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.location.GMS_CORE_LOCATION qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{cb66323 4600:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search/u0a68}
06-05 12:22:32.972 3510-4040/? D/NetworkPolicy: isUidForegroundLocked: 10068, mScreenOn: true, uidstate: 2, mProxSensorScreenOff: false
06-05 12:22:32.982 3510-7360/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 3 index 90
06-05 12:22:32.982 3510-3971/? I/Sensors: ProximitySensor - 8(cm)
06-05 12:22:32.992 4600-11315/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ah@ef02224
06-05 12:22:32.992 3140-3989/? I/APM::AudioPolicyManager: getInputForAttr() source 6, samplingRate 16000, format 1, channelMask 10,session 84, flags 0
06-05 12:22:32.992 3140-3989/? V/audio_hw_primary: adev_open_input_stream: request sample_rate:16000
06-05 12:22:32.992 3140-3989/? V/audio_hw_primary: in->requested_rate:16000, pcm_config_in.rate:48000 in->config.channels=2
06-05 12:22:32.992 3140-3989/? D/audio_hw_primary: adev_open_input_stream: call echoReference_init(12)
06-05 12:22:32.992 3140-3989/? V/echo_reference_processing: echoReference_init +
06-05 12:22:32.992 3140-3989/? I/audio_hw_primary: adev_open_input_stream: input is null, set new input stream
06-05 12:22:32.992 4600-11932/? D/SensorManager: Proximity, val = 8.0  [far]
06-05 12:22:32.992 3510-3555/? I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager$8c7dfbdcom.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.c.a$1$c7409b2 req=4flags=0x0
06-05 12:22:32.992 3140-11937/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xecac0000 ready to run
06-05 12:22:33.012 4600-11317/? W/CronetAsyncHttpEngine: Upload request without a content type.
06-05 12:22:33.012 4600-12335/? I/FavoriteContactNamesSup: get()
06-05 12:22:33.012 4600-12335/? I/FavoriteContactNamesSup: get() : Execute directly (BG thread)
06-05 12:22:33.012 4600-12335/? I/FavoriteContactNamesSup: get()
06-05 12:22:33.012 4600-12335/? I/FavoriteContactNamesSup: get() : Execute directly (BG thread)
06-05 12:22:33.012 4600-12335/? I/FavoriteContactNamesSup: get()
06-05 12:22:33.012 3510-4533/? D/BatteryService: !@BatteryListener : batteryPropertiesChanged!
06-05 12:22:33.012 4600-12335/? I/FavoriteContactNamesSup: get() : Execute directly (BG thread)
06-05 12:22:33.012 3510-4533/? D/BatteryService: level:80, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4093, temperature: 337, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, POGO powered:false, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303446, invalid charger:0, maxChargingCurrent:0
06-05 12:22:33.012 3510-4533/? D/BatteryService: online:4, current avg:48, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false, capacity:280000, batterySWSelfDischarging:false, current_now:240
06-05 12:22:33.012 3510-3510/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
06-05 12:22:33.022 11753-11753/com.aaa.bbb D/SpeechManager: onError: Error 7
```

And here's my code:

```
public class SpeechManager {

private static final String TAG = "SpeechManager";
private final MainActivity mActivity;
private final SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
private boolean mTurnedOn = false;
private final Intent mRecognitionIntent;
private final Handler mHandler;

public SpeechManager(@NonNull MainActivity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new MySpeechRecognizer());

    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    mRecognitionIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
//  mRecognitionIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mRecognitionIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, false);
    mRecognitionIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
}

public void startSpeechRecognition() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startSpeechRecognition: ");
    mTurnedOn = true;
    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mRecognitionIntent);
}

public void stopSpeechRecognition() {
    Log.d(TAG, "stopSpeechRecognition: ");
    if (mTurnedOn) {
        mTurnedOn = false;
        mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
    }
}

public void destroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "destroy: ");
    mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
}

private class MySpeechRecognizer implements RecognitionListener {
    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech: Beginning");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech: Ending");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onError: Error " + error);
        if (error == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK || error == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT) {
            mTurnedOn = false;
            return;
        }

        if (mTurnedOn)
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
//                  mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
                    startSpeechRecognition();
                }
            }, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResults: ");
        ArrayList<String> partialResults = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        if (partialResults != null && partialResults.size() > 0) {
            for (String str : partialResults) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResults: " + str);
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(mActivity.getString(R.string.turn_off_recognition))) {
                    FlashManager.getInstance().turnOff();
                    mTurnedOn = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startSpeechRecognition();
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: " + eventType);
    }
}
}
```

My device is Samsung Note5. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug, which I filed a report on. You can reproduce the issue [using this simple gist](https://gist.github.com/brandall76/b911eb732f309dec68af351d74013851).

<strike>The only way around it, is to recreate the `SpeechRecognizer` object every time.</strike> **see edit**. This causes other issues, as mentioned in the gist, but none that will cause a problem for your app.

Google will eventually find a way to prevent continuous listening, as it's not what the API was designed for. You're better off looking at [PocketSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) as a long term option.

**EDIT 22.06.16** - With the most recent Google release, the behaviour has changed for the worse. A new solution is linked from the gist which subclasses the `RecognitionListener` to only react to 'genuine' callbacks.

**EDIT 01.07.16"** - See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150312/google-speech-recognition-timeout) for another new bug

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct. Google speech recognition is linked to their "Google App".
Since version 5.10 (Feb.2016) things have started to go wrong and with recent version 6 it is a complete mess! See my thread here in the Basic4Android forum: https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/google-speech-recognition-sr-not-working-properly-anymore.68871/

Comment: So it was Feb 2016 when [the mayhem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74910231/2597758) started? :)