# Is android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE officially supported?

Tags: android, version, speech-recognition, slowdown

I cannot find documentation about that possible extra.
I have to use it because it seems to be the only real workaround I could find during the last days to overcome the slow down issue of speech recognition after the last Google releases, following the @vladbph answer in [a specific post about Google Speech Recognition Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150312/google-speech-recognition-timeout/38534808#38534808).
I tested his workaround for hours and it seems to work, but which future support can I expect about the use of that extra? And on which Android versions is it available?

Comment: Your're right! It can not be found in the document.
What does it seem to work for you?

Answer (score 1):

As of Android API level 23 there is no public static final String defined/documented for "android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE" (if this is what you mean by "officially supported").

Comment: Well, I  think my first meaning of "officially supported" is in the last part of my original question ("which future support can I expect and on which Android versions is it available").

Comment: In the mewnwhile I continued testing and empirically I found it is available at least since API 16 to API 23, which is my current target range. Nevertheless, now I just experienced that it works for that specific purpose, without knowing its real meaning, if not by inferring it by the English words the costant is composed by... this is rarely a good approach, so I'm asking every other insight about its meaning, not to be excessively surprised by unexpected behavior