# onRmsChanged not called after first time in RecognitionLIstener Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm developing an app in which i need tts. I've implemented RecognitionListener and it works fine the first time. After that it still listens and returns results but onRmsChanged is no longer being called.

Here is my method which starts the speech recognition:

```
private void promptSpeechInput(String langCode) {
    Intent speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
            mContext.getPackageName());
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
            langCode);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    mIsSpeechRecognitionOn = true;
    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(speechIntent);
}
```

And my class which implements RecognitionListener:

```
public class ConversationFragment extends Fragment implements RecognitionListener {

private final String LOG_TAG = ConversationFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;

private Translator mTranslator;

private SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
private TextToSpeech mTextToSpeech;
private View mRootView;
private TranslationPanel mTranslationPanel;
private RecyclerView mConversationView;
private TextView mEmptyConversationView;

private ChatAdapter mConversationAdapter;
private Set<Locale> mLocales;

public ConversationFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation, container, false);
    mTranslator = new Translator(getContext());
    setupSpeechRecognizer();
    mTranslationPanel = new TranslationPanel(getContext(), mRootView, mSpeechRecognizer);

    mTextToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                mLocales = mTextToSpeech.getAvailableLanguages();
            }

            mConversationAdapter.setTextToSpeech(mTextToSpeech);
        }
    });

    mEmptyConversationView = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_conversation_textview);
    mConversationView = (RecyclerView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.conversation_container);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setStackFromEnd(true);

    mConversationView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    List<Translation> translations = Translation.listAll(Translation.class);
    mConversationAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getContext(), translations);
    mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationAdapter);
    mConversationView.scrollToPosition(mConversationAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);

    if (translations == null || translations.size() == 0) {
        mConversationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mEmptyConversationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    checkMicrophonePermission();

    return mRootView;
}

public void checkMicrophonePermission() {
    int microphonePermission =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    if (microphonePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mTranslationPanel.getLeftTranslator().setEnabled(true);
                mTranslationPanel.getRightTranslator().setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mTranslationPanel.getLeftTranslator().setEnabled(false);
                mTranslationPanel.getRightTranslator().setEnabled(false);
            }
    }
}


private void setupSpeechRecognizer() {
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getContext());
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mTextToSpeech != null) {
        mTextToSpeech.shutdown();
    }
    if (mSpeechRecognizer != null) {
        mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
    }
}

private void translate(final String text) {
    String leftLanguageCode = Utility.getCodeFromLanguage(getContext(),
            Utility.getTranslatorLanguage(getContext(), Utility.LEFT_TRANSLATOR_LANGUAGE));
    String rightLanguageCode = Utility.getCodeFromLanguage(getContext(),
            Utility.getTranslatorLanguage(getContext(), Utility.RIGHT_TRANSLATOR_LANGUAGE));

    Callback<TranslationResult> callback = new Callback<TranslationResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TranslationResult> call, Response<TranslationResult> response) {
            final TranslationResult translation = response.body();
            final String lang = translation.getLang();

            String translatedText = translation.getText()[0];

            Translation chatTranslation = mTranslationPanel.hasJustUsedLeftTranslator() ?
                    new Translation(translatedText, text, true, lang) :
                    new Translation(translatedText, text, false, lang);

            if (mConversationView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                mConversationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEmptyConversationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            mConversationAdapter.addTranslation(chatTranslation);

            chatTranslation.save();

            if (mConversationAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                mConversationView.scrollToPosition(mConversationAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
            }

            speakText(translatedText, lang);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TranslationResult> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Something went wrong.");
        }
    };

    if (mTranslationPanel.hasJustUsedLeftTranslator()) {
        mTranslator.translate(text, leftLanguageCode + "-" + rightLanguageCode, callback);
    } else {
        mTranslator.translate(text, rightLanguageCode + "-" + leftLanguageCode, callback);
    }
}

private void speakText(String text, String language) {
    if (mTextToSpeech == null || mTextToSpeech.isSpeaking() || mLocales == null) {
        return;
    }

    String langCode = Utility.getTranslatedLanguage(language);

    if (langCode.equals(getString(R.string.lang_code_bg))) {
        langCode = getString(R.string.lang_code_ru);
        text = Utility.editBulgarianTextForRussianReading(text);
    }

    Locale locale = Utility.getLocaleFromLangCode(langCode, mLocales);
    if (locale == null) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Language not supported by TextToSpeech.");
        return;
    }

    mTextToSpeech.setLanguage(locale);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mTextToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
    } else {
        mTextToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReadyforSpeach");
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    mTranslationPanel.setAnimationOn(true);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeach");
}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    mTranslationPanel.onRmsChanged(rmsdB);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged");
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived");
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    mTranslationPanel.setAnimationOn(false);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeach");
}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {
    String errorMessage = getErrorText(error);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
    mTranslationPanel.setAnimationOn(false);
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ArrayList<String> matches = results
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

    String text = null;
    if (matches != null) {
        text = matches.get(0);
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, text);

    translate(text);
}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
}

public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
    String message;
    switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            break;
    }
    return message;
}
```

}

I've searched all over the internet for a solution but haven't found one and if someone could help me i would really appreciate it.

Comment: It's a bug in the current Google Now application - see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38150919/1256219

Comment: Have you found a solution? Same problem here...

Comment: @Klemens Well, I don't know if you can call it really a solution but I've noticed that if you call speechRecognizer.startListening() and right after that speechRecognizer.cancel() in the onResults method of the recognitionListener you start getting onRmsChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void onResults(Bundle results)
    {
        ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        mText.setText("results: "+data.get(0));
        sr.startListening(intent);
        sr.cancel();
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly the way I managed to fix it, but thanks anyway.