# SpeechRecognizer, bind to recognition service failed

Tags: android, speech-recognition, bindservice

I used SpeechRecognizer on android to recognize the User's voice.
It worked well until uninstall the Google App. 
(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=en)

I updated the Google App, but I got errors such as "bind to recognition service failed".
How can I make the app run successfully?

What should I do to use SpeechRecognizer normally?

Thanks.

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64319117/1423773

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319117/speechrecognizer-not-available-when-targeting-android-11) is helpful to solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the Google app is updated some way or the other there is always an issue with the speech recognizer callbacks. Either Google periodically changes their timeout clause or some weird issues like yours pops out of nowhere.

You need to make your code dynamic in such a way that even if there is an error in the speech callback methods, you need to catch that error and try listening again automatically. This has been discussed widely in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38150312/4023485) and there are plenty of answers provided for you to check and implement them based on your requirement.

If you don't want this you can always try out [DroidSpeech](https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech) library which takes care of these speech error issues whenever something pops up and provides you with continuous voice recognition.

Just implement the library using Gradle and add the following lines of code.

> DroidSpeech droidSpeech = new DroidSpeech(this, null);
> droidSpeech.setOnDroidSpeechListener(this);

To start listening to the user call the below code,

> droidSpeech.startDroidSpeechRecognition();

And you will get the voice result in the listener method,

> @Override
>
> public void onDroidSpeechFinalResult(String
> finalSpeechResult, boolean droidSpeechWillListen)
> {
>
> }

Answer (score 15):

#### Update manifest

I'm using Algolia's voice input library and it was failing to take voice input on Pixel 2 and android 11 devices. The reason being unable to bind to voice recognition service.

To solve it, In the manifest file, insert this query element just under your   ​opening tag:

```
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"/>
</queries>
```

Comment: Thanks! Still actual in 2021 and your response was the only thing which fixed the issue on Pixel 3a.

Comment: this answer should be the propper solution. thanks bud

Comment: Filtering by intent also works
    `<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>`

Comment: Who else finds it crazy insane and infuriating that this appeared NOWHERE even close to any Documentation related to `SpeechRecognizer`? This is 2021. Still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am answering this a bit late but I have struggled with this error for a while now. It turns out you need to activate Google's Quick Search Box. So the solution I used is: I check if the SpeechRecognizer is available (using `isRecognitionAvailable(context)`). If the SpeechRecognizer is not available, you can activate it like this :

```
if(!SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(mainActivity)){
    String appPackageName = "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox";
    try {
        mainActivity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        mainActivity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, it just opens a PlayStore page with google app. Adding "queries" into manifest (see above) resolved the issue on Pixel 3a.

Comment: @ARA1307 I think the right solution is to combine the two solutions because some clients don't have Google's Quick Search Box installed/enabled on their devices (which will not be resolved only by adding "queries" to your manifest) . Anyways, happy that the other solution worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this in the manifest like so:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
**<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
    </intent>
</queries>**
```